# Chat with ASP.NET and SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ajax, chat

I have to program a chat with asp.net.

The messages are saved in a SQL Server database.

How can I retrieve the messages from the database in real time?

If an other user write a message, how can I know it?

I saw something about `SqlCacheDependency` polling and pushing, but I don't want to always refresh the page. It's maybe better to use `SqlDependency`, or maybe ajax?

Do you have some idea?

Somebody has some code example?

Comment: I have recently done something similar.  You could use AJAX and poll the server every 2/3 seconds and request new content or you could use SignalR. http://signalr.net/

Comment: you mean to use the updatePanel with the sqlcachedependency or something different?

Comment: http://davidfowl.github.io/JabbR/

Comment: I would agree with @Phill Go and read up on JabbR and how it uses SignalR to provide real-time communication in a chat room format.

Comment: thanks a lot. what do ou think about using a ajax UpdatePanel, with a Timer that every 2 seconds call the function that select data from database?

Comment: @Marc - jQuery AJAX - but SignalR will be your best option.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this, it's best framework to do **`real time chat's`** 
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: thanks a lot. what do you think about using a ajax UpdatePanel, with a Timer that every 2 seconds call the function that select data from database?

Comment: Ohhhh god no use only client do not implement it with UpdatePanel only JQuery and SignalR C# for Db Work

Comment: ahah.. thanks.. I thought it was crazy... and to use updatePanel with sqlcache dependency polling?    the sqlcache dependency control database every 2 seconds. if datas change it reloads the query, else it use the cache where he saved last datas.    what do you think? it's crazy?